# C++: Program going in infinite loop when running a function

Tags: c++, linked-list, infinite-loop

I have written a function to merge 2 sorted linked lists. But before I could know if the logic I came up with is correct, I encountered an infinite loop as soon as the function is called. I'm not sure why it happens. Below is the code:

```
ListNode *merge_sorted_list(ListNode *head1, ListNode *head2) {
    cout<<"hi\n";
    ListNode *curr = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode *start = curr;
    cout<<"hi\n";
    while(head1 || head2) {
        if(head1->val == head2->val) {
            curr->next = head1;
            curr = curr->next;
            curr->next = head2;
            if(head1) head1 = head1->next;
            if(head2) head2 = head2->next;
        } else if(head1->val < head2->val) {
            curr->next = head1;
            curr = curr->next;
            if(head1) head1 = head1->next;
        } else {
            curr->next = head2;
            curr = curr->next;
            if(head2) head2 = head2->next;
        }
    }
    return start->next;

}
```

I'm not able to print 'hi' on the console window. Also, head1 and head2 are not NULL values.
Kindly help.
**Update:** Able to see 'hi' now.

Comment: Remember that the standard output is line buffered, so perhaps you will see your printout if you change it to `"hi\n"`.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasPadron-McCarthy! I'm able to see 'hi' now. But still the code runs infinitely. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger?

Comment: What if one of list nodes in `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

first, you are destroying head1 and head2 because you wrote

```
curr->next = head1;
```

and later:

```
curr->next = head2;
```

So you are mixing both and at the end you maybe have some memoryleaks.

So you want to combine both lists to a new list. so try this:

```
ListNode *merge_sorted_list(ListNode *head1, ListNode *head2) 
{
    ListNode* pReturn = new ListNode();
    ListNode* tempRet = pReturn;
    ListNode* temp1 = head1;
    ListNode* temp2 = head2;

    while(temp1 != nullptr || temp2 != nullptr)
    {
        if(temp1 && temp2)
        {
            if(temp1->val < temp2->val)
            {
                tempRet->next = new ListNode(temp1); //the constructor should copy the ListNode value
                tempRet = tempRet->next;
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            else if(temp1->val > temp2->val)
            {
                tempRet->next = new ListNode(temp2);
                tempRet = tempRet->next;
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
            else //doubled value
            {
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
        }
        else if(temp1)
        {
            while(temp1)
            {
                tempRet->next = new ListNode(temp1);
                tempRet = tempRet -> next;
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
        }
        else if(temp2)
        {
            while(temp2)
            {
                tempRet->next = new ListNode(temp2);
                tempRet = tempRet -> next;
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return pReturn;
}
```